# javascript - Create an iframe that loads the same page where is placed- IframeLoop

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm making a Wordpress site and I need that a page load itself in an iframe inside of it.
It's like the inception movie!
My problem is that urls of the pages are dynamic.

Actually I need a script that append an iframe in a specific div...I've tried with this line of code but it doesn't work:

```
jQuery(".reloaddivxxx").append(" <iframe src=\"(window.location.href)\"></iframe> ");
```

I'm not sure if it's clear what I need to do...
I need to create an iframe that loads the page where is placed and get the url of that page dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the url of an iframe with JavaScript, after getting the URL of the current page.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var iframe = window.frames[0];
iframe.location = url;
```

*Edit 1:*

If you're inserting the iframe dynamically as well, you have to either get the reference to the iframe after inserting it, or before. Here's an example of the latter:

```
var url = window.location.href;

// Create the iframe using jquery, and set the url of it.
var iframe = $("<iframe>");
iframe[0].src = url;

// Insert the iframe into the div.
jQuery(".reloaddivxxx").append(iframe);
```

Comment: I can't make it work...i've tried this but it doesn't work...`var url = window.location.href;
var iframe = window.frames[0];
iframe.location = url;
jQuery(".reloaddivxxx").append(" <iframe src=(url) ></iframe> ");`   --- i need to study...:-(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.width = '100px';
iframe.style.height = '100px';
iframe.src = window.location.href;

document.getElementsByClassName('reloaddivxxx')[0].appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: Hi,Pierfrancesco..It works perfectly, the script create an i-frame that loads the entire page inside itself. Thanks a lot!! There is the possibility to add a "/" at the end of the url ?! Again tanks a lot!!

Comment: `iframe.src = window.location.href + '/';`